# Irreducibility over $\mathbb{C}$ of symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

**Problem**. Find all elementary symmetric polynomials that are irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$.

**My attempt**.

1. It's easy to see that if we have polynomial $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and it can be reduced to $g(x_1, \dots, x_n) \cdot h(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ then without loss of generality $g = g(x_1, \dots, x_k)$ and $h = h(x_{k+1}, \dots, x_n)$.
2. $g$ is symmetric towards $x_1, \dots, x_k$ and $h$ towards $x_{k+1}, \dots, x_n$.
3. Number of summands in $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ if $\deg(f) = l$ is $n \choose l$. Number of summands in $g, \deg(g) = s$ and $f$ are: $k \choose s$ and $n -k \choose l-s$. But ${n \choose l} > {k \choose s}{n -k \choose l-s}$ since there are more possibilities to choose $l$ elements from $n$ than to separate $n$ elements into $2$ groups of $k$ and $n-k$ elements and choose from one group $s$ elements and from the other $l-s$.

Comment: I would note that these polynomials have degree $1$ with respect to each variable taken individually.

Comment: Unfortunately maybe they can be reduced to non-symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Well, imagine you could write a factorization of the polynomial into irreducible factors. How many of these could $x_1$ appear in?

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if nothing of what the OP attempted to do cannot be fixed. If he has not tried anything or does not have any idea at all, then I personally, given the level of the question, think that the very best thing for me —at least— to do is to recommend him to spend more time on the problem.

Comment: @Jihad, if the possibility that they may be reducible to non-symmetric polynomials is a problem, maybe you should try to see if that possibility acctually occurs.

Comment: I think providing an initial direction of investigation is more useful than presuming that Jihad doesn't need any help. If he didn't need help, he wouldn't be here asking the question.

Comment: Please open a meta thread if you think you need to discuss this (you should probably first search the existing ones on the subject, and read them...) *Here* that discussion is off-topic.

Comment: I don't see the qualitative difference between what I wrote and what you wrote. Oh well.

Comment: With respect to your edit, it is correct. However, I would find it easiest to go straight to a decomposition into a product of irreducible factors. Then think about these questions of symmetry.

Comment: Is it ok now?...

Comment: It's mainly okay. You probably should point out that the homogeneity of $f$ implies that of $g$ and $h$. Also, you have an exception when $l = n$ and $s = k$.

Comment: Yes, of course, but it is obvious for mentioning).

Comment: Jihad, it might be preferable to explicitly identify a term that can't appear in the product, since this is required to prove the inequality anyway. For example, clearly we have $s < l$ since $g$ and $h$ are non-constant. Now assume further that $s < k$. Then no term in the product $gh$ can contain $x_1 x_2 \dots x_{s + 1}$ as a factor, which is a contradiction. Thus $s = k$. Similarly, $l - s = n - k$. This proves $l = n$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98474/is-an-elementary-symmetric-polynomial-an-irreducible-element-in-the-polynomial-r .

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_k$ be the symmetric polynomial of degree $k$ in the variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Write $e_k$ as a product $cf_1 \dots f_r$, with each $f_i$ irreducible.

Since $e_k$ has degree one with respect to each variable, each variable must appear in precisely one of the factors $f_1, \dots, f_r$, resulting in a corresponding partition $E_1$, $E_2$, ..., $E_r$ of the set of variables. By the uniqueness of the decomposition, permuting the variables must result, essentially, in the same decomposition (with an irreducible factor at worst being multiplied by a nonzero constant), hence in the same partition of the variables.

This can be achieved in only two ways. Either $r = 1$, or else $r = n$ and each $E_i$ has cardinality one.

If $r = 1$, then $e_k$ is irreducible.

In the other case, the degree of $e_k$ must be at least $n$, so we must have $k = n$.